# get all index values from nested array in json response

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have json response and wants to get some data from it.
Here's my json response code:

```json
{
"links": [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "et porro tempora",
    "completed": true
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "title": "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    "completed": false
  }
]
}
```

Please help me to get all values of title and append them to html span tag.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you tried, and what exactly did not work and/or what errors you got.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the response to JSON.parse() function and then iterate over the "links" object

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
for(var i=0;i<data.links.length;i++){
    console.log(data.links[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to Deaguve answer. I just added JSON.stringify(json) to JSON.parse and console logged titles.

```
let parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
for(let i = 0; i < parsed.links.length; i++) {
    console.log(parsed.links[i].title);
}
```